# How to handle a back button in a screen that has a tab navigator React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I have a general drawer menu for the app, and in one of the screens there is a tab navigator. I'm trying to handle the back button because it throws an error that there is no screen to go back to. I saw on the documentation for react navigation that you use useFocusEffect with React.useCallback, but when I tried it, it gave me an undefined is not a function (near 0, _react,useFocusEffect) error.

Here is the code I used:

```
export default function BudgetScreen({ navigation }) {

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const handleBackButton = () => {
        navigation.goBack()
        return true;
      }

      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);

      return () =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);
    }, [])
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `useFocusEffect` like this:

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Comment: I did that, I just didn't copy over my imports in the code